# How can I access the scenario and example names in Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber

I'm using cucumber to generate test scripts that can be executed by a tool or human... so not the standard use.

However I would like to pass through the scenario and example names through to my output.

Is this possible?

Comment: I am expecting the solution to be something like 

Before do |scenario|
   puts scenario.name
end

but it doesn't have a name method and scenario object seems to be an Cucumber::Ast::OutlineTable::ExampleCells in my case as I am using Scenario Outlines

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it.. (with some help from Tim Walker)

```
Before do |scenario|
 puts "Before Scenario: #{scenario.to_sexp[2]}"
 .
 .
 .
end
```

Your SExpression may differ, so it's worth doing a `scenario.to_sexp.inspect` to see what that tree is.

Aslak is keen to avoid exposing properties on his classes (which is a decision I happen to agree with, so I'm happy to do this work around).

Comment: `scenario.name` seems to work fine on current versions of Cucumber.

Answer (score 2):

A more serious answer (or at least, suggestion): make use of ruby's reflection to try to find what you are looking for.  Grab likely objects, find out what methods they have, and see if you can find it.  For example:

```
File.open('happy_hunting.log','a') { |f|
    f.print "Scenario supports: #{(scenario.methods - Object.methods).inspect}\n"
    }
```

and then repeat it to figure out whats where.

Another suggestion, look at the source.

Comment: That doesn't work because there is no scenario object available within the scenario -- unless you capture it with a Before block, as shown in Nigel's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did something scrappy. As I use this info for only debugging, this will work for now, until I find something better.

```
@Before
public void printTestInfoBeforeScenario(Scenario scenario) {
    LOGGER.info("Upcoming Test: "+scenario.getSourceTagNames());
}

@After
public void printTestInfoAfterScenario(Scenario scenario) {
    LOGGER.info("Test Complete: " + scenario.getSourceTagNames() + " Status: " + scenario.getStatus());
}
```